# I might need help with this probability question involving addition and product rules?

Tags: probability, statistics

My problem is the following.

> Two dice are thrown and their sum is noted. Find the probability of getting:
>
> A total of 2

My answer was 1/6.

My intuition tells me that these events are independent events meaning these events cannot be affected by any another event. The sample space of all the possible outcomes is {1,2,3,4,5,6}, so the first roll would be (1/6) and the second roll will still be (1/6).

Therefore, the probability is 1/6.

Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but your way of calculating the probability is not.

As the only combination of getting $2$ from $6$ dice is to roll $1$ first, then $1$ again, we can calculate the probability for each event. $P(A = rolls \ a \ 1 \ first) = \frac{1}{6}$, and $P(B = rolls \ a \ 1 \ second) = \frac{1}{6}$, but notice that we need **both** $P(A)$ **and** $P(B)$ to happen. For example, if event $A$ happens but $B$ doesn't, such as in the roll $(1,2)$, then this case should not be counted.

To get $P(A \ and \ B)$, by the multiplication rule of probability we should multiply $P(A)$, which is $\frac{1}{6}$; and $P(B)$, which is also $ \frac{1}{6}$. What is the probability using this method?

Comment: The probability should be 1/36, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank-you very much Toby, next time I have a problem like this I won't forget to multiply their probability's. Cheers have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

Since the sum is $2$, and we are working with natural numbers, the only method to have a sum of two if both the dies, $D_1$ and $D_2$, are at $1$.

The probability of $D_1$ coming to $1$ is, as you said, $1\over6$. But of the events where $D_1$ is $1\over6$, there are six possiblities of $D_2$. Of those, the probability is $1\over6$. So, the total probabilty is ${{{1}\over{6}}\cdot{{1}\over{6}}}={{1}\over{36}}$

---

A Simpler Approach:
$
({1,1})({2,1})({3,1})({4,1})({5,1})({6,1})\\
({1,2})({2,2})({3,2})({4,2})({5,2})({6,2})\\
({1,3})({2,3})({3,3})({4,3})({5,3})({6,3})\\
({1,4})({2,4})({3,4})({4,4})({5,4})({6,4})\\
({1,5})({2,5})({3,5})({4,5})({5,5})({6,5})\\
({1,6})({2,6})({3,6})({4,6})({5,6})({6,6})\\$

$(1,1)$ appears only once, out of $36$ times. Therefore, probability is $1\over{36}$

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo There's just one problem with this method - what happens when we have a similar case, but with a $100$-sided die? Writing all the possibilities will be pretty much impossible in that case.

Comment: @TobyMak That's why I added it as an afterthought. The original, more general method is on top.